# What is the maximum level in Bound by Flame?

Tags: bound-by-flame

I'm interested in getting Bound by Flame for the PC, but I'm curious as to what the maximum level is.

Comment: I've edited your question, as we don't allow "How long to beat" questions. That said, [How Long to Beat](http://www.howlongtobeat.com/game.php?id=18141) lists it as 10-22 hours depending on how thorough you want to be.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of people are under the belief that the level cap is 25, however people have found they can surpass that level.

This is still very much up for discussion, but the common belief is that there isn't really a level cap. The levelling system appears to be similar to Skyrim (pre-DLC) where the level cap is at the end of the skill tree. This is to say: you stop gaining levels when you have nothing left to level-up.

Answer (score 1):

There does not appear to be a level cap. While [some](http://ca.ign.com/articles/2014/03/25/the-combat-crafting-and-demonic-choice-in-bound-by-flame) claim that the maximum level is 25, [this thread](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/706033-bound-by-flame/69210211) reports an individual reaching level 26, and [this thread](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/706032-bound-by-flame/69221717) features an individual claiming to be level 33.

Based on speculation in both of these threads, there does not appear to be a level cap. However there are 2 things you should note:

- The higher the level, the progressively more XP needed to advance. For example, to reach level 34, the individual above claims to need 46,500 XP.
- Costs remain the same, meaning that you may need to level up multiple times (which would involve excessive amounts of grinding) in order to purchase Feats or Skills that cost multiple points.